# why multiple data doesn't insert in this code

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tbl_employee table and tbl_time table, I want to insert multiple data insert for attendance but when I click submit button it's insert only single data . but where is the problem ,help me to find out this..this is insert code

```
require './db_connect.php';
class Time extends Db_connect {

    protected $link;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->link = $this->database_connection();
    }

    public function attendance_insert($data) {
        extract($data);
        $cur_date = date('Y-m-d');

        foreach ($time_attendance as $attn_key => $attn_value) {
            if ($attn_value == 'P') {
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_time(employee_id,time_date,time_attendance)VALUES('$attn_key','$cur_date','P')";
                $atten_date=mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL);
            } else if ($attn_value == 'A') {
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_time(employee_id,time_date,time_attendance)VALUES('$attn_key','$cur_date','A')";
                $atten_date=mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL);

            }
            if ($atten_date) {
                $massage = "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'><h5>Attendance insert successfully</h5></div>";
                return $massage;
            } else {
                die('Attendance insert query problem' . mysqli_error($this->link));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is html code

```
<?php

    require_once './time.php';
    $obj_time = new Time()
    $massage = '';
    if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
        $massage = $obj_time->attendance_insert($_POST);
    }

    $employee_view = $obj_employee->employee_all_view();
    ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <center>
                <a href="time.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-backward pull-left" id="show_form"></a>
                <span style="font-size:1.8em;">Attendance form</span>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>


    <?php echo $massage; ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="panel panel-body panel-default">
                    <div class="well text-center" style="font-size:15px;">
                        <strong>Date :</strong>
                        <?php $current_date = date('Y-M-d');
                        echo $current_date; ?>
                    </div>
                    <form  class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <td><b>Serial</b></td>
                                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                                <td><b>ID</b></td>
                                <td><b>Attendance</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $i = 0;
                            while ($employee_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($employee_view)) {
                                extract($employee_info);
                                $i++;
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $employee_first_name . ' ' . $employee_last_name; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $employee_id; ?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="radio" name="time_attendance[<?php echo $employee_id; ?>]" value="P">P &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="time_attendance[<?php echo $employee_id; ?>]" value="A">A
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="btn" value="submit"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why only insert single row .........please give me solution.............

Comment: Is there any problem in my code ............

Comment: linking back, so meta https://laurent22.github.io/so-injections/
your code is vulnerable to very nasty attacks

Comment: Don't use `extract()`, it's a bad habit and will probably literally blow up data. Learn to use array and loop, that's more reliable ;)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: It looks like you’re in the process of writing your own Object Relationship Manager (ORM). PHP already has many of these which are tested, documented, and have considerable community support. Have a look at  [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before re-inventing the wheel. This code has a number of very serious issues that will be very time-consuming to properly resolve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This :

```
foreach($time_attendance as $attn_key => $attn_value){
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_time(employee_id,time_date,time_attendance) 
        VALUES('$attn_key','$cur_date','A')";
    $atten_date = mysqli_query($this->link, $SQL);

    if ($atten_date) {
        $massage = "<div class=''><h5>Attendance insert successfully</h5></div>";
        return $massage;
    }
}
```

Literally ask to break the foreach with `return $massage;` if you query succeed... So yes, you'll only have one record.

Put your return outside the foreach.

Comment: @Md.ShapanHossain no problem; if you want some improvement take a look at how [`INSERT INTO` are safely used here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ; and for your test of successful, test the other way : if there is an error ($atten_date==FALSE) add a message, if no massage in the var after the foreach, then display "everything ok"